# Bootstrap Carousel with asp.net not working

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, slider

I am using bootstrap carousel slider in asp.net. I want to do repeater control carousel slider. But not working. How can I do.

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="about-slider">
            <div id="carousel-slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <!-- Indicators -->
               <ol class="carousel-indicators visible-xs">
                    <li data-target="#carousel-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                     <div class="item active">
                        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
                            <ItemTemplate>                                  
              <img src='/resimler/<%#Eval("SliderResim")%>' class="img-responsive" alt="">       
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                    </div>
                   </div>
                <a class="left carousel-control hidden-xs" href="#carousel-slider" data-slide="prev">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control hidden-xs" href="#carousel-slider" data-slide="next">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
            <!--/#carousel-slider-->
        </div>
        <!--/#about-slider-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a little mistake in your repeater. the `<div class="item active">` must be inside your `<ItemTemplate>` alongside with the contents.
It's the div and the class `.item` that makes the slides on the carousel.

But be careful, only one div must have the `.active`, indicating which div should be shown. The other divs should have only the `.item` class, as the carousel controls will change the `.active` class this dynamically as the user interact with the carousel.

A simple example using the first index to set the `.active` class, and only `.item` otherwise.

```
<div class="slider">
<div class="container">
    <div id="about-slider">
        <div id="carousel-slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
           <ol class="carousel-indicators visible-xs">
                <li data-target="#carousel-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                    <div <%# Container.ItemIndex == 0 ? "class=\"item active\"" : "class=\"item\"" %>>
                    <img src='/resimler/<%#Eval("SliderResim")%>' class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    </div>    
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
               </div>
            <a class="left carousel-control hidden-xs" href="#carousel-slider" data-slide="prev">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control hidden-xs" href="#carousel-slider" data-slide="next">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
        <!--/#carousel-slider-->
    </div>
    <!--/#about-slider-->
</div>
```

Comment: This ' <%# Container.ItemIndex == 0 ? "class=\"item active\"" : "class=\"item\"" %>'  code is awesome